# TinyMCE 'forced root block' causes problem with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tinymce-4

When I change `forced_root_block` to false in the TinyMCE configuration, it is causing trouble when typing spaces in Google Chrome. The space bar seems to 'hang'. There is no problem with Microsoft Edge. I am not sure when this problem started, since I do not use Chrome all the time, but I guess only recently. I am using this setting because I want linebreaks `<br>` instead of paragraphs `<p>` with the enter key.

I tried to reproduce this behaviour in the code snippet below, but I can't get it to run. Anyway, here is the [same example](http://www.esims.nl/test/stackoverflow/02/tinymce_example.html?v=2) on my own website. Can this problem be fixed, or is it a Chrome issue?

**Edit:** it appears that there is also a problem with spaces using Internet Explorer, regardless of the `forced_root_block` setting. Although the space bar does not hang, it produces &nbsp; instead of normal spaces. I therefore presume the problem is related to TinyMCE, rather than the browser.

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 150,
  width: 400,
  theme: 'modern',
  verify_html: false,
  menubar: false,
  statusbar: false,
  forced_root_block: false,
  paste_as_text: true,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
  ],
  toolbar1: 'bold italic | link | forecolor backcolor emoticons emoji | removeformat',
  contextmenu: 'paste | link image inserttable | cell row column deletetable',
  image_advtab: true,

  relative_urls: false,
  remove_script_host: true,
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <textarea id="fldMessage" cols="58" rows="15" runat="server"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `forced_root_block: false` you are telling TinyMCE to insert a `<br>` when enter is pressed as opposed to creating a new block element (`<p>`).

What are you wanting to have happen when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed?  TinyMCE will either create a new block or insert a line break - are you wanting some other behavior?  If so you will need to capture the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press and do what you want programmatically.

Comment: I indeed want a `<br>` instead of a `<p>`. Just like the behaviour of the enter key in any text editor. `forced_root_block: false` is the setting to achieve this. Except it doesn't work right (anymore) in every browser, I discovered today.

Comment: So what is the exact issue then?  Is it the `<br>` or something else?  What does `&nbsp;` have to do with the issue?

Comment: If normal spaces are replaced with `&nbsp`, you don't have line wrap. This replacement does not occur with Microsoft Edge. And with Chrome, the space bar seems to 'hang'. Actually you are right, this is a different issue I discovered after having trouble with Chrome.

Comment: TinyMCE will replace every other space with a non-breaking space as otherwise HTML does not render multiple whitespace characters.  In my brief test TinyMCE does this in IE, Edge, Chrome, etc.

Comment: This is how it should work, I agree. I have added a 'Show Html' button to the example page I mentioned above. You will see that Internet Explorer replaces all single spaces by non-breaking spaces. Chrome 'hangs' all the time; you need to press space twice and delete one. Only Microsoft Edge works normally.

Comment: TinyMCE 4.9.1 (released today) has a fix that states "FIXED a bug where the space bar didn't work correctly in editors with the forced_root_block setting set to false."  Try that version and see if that fixes your issue.